# Float type storing values in format "2.46237846387469E+15"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table `ProductAmount` with columns

```
Id [BIGINT]
Amount [FLOAT]
```

now when I pass value from my form to table it gets stored in format `2.46237846387469E+15` whereas actual value was `2462378463874687`. Any ideas why this value is being converted and how to stop this?

Comment: You can use Decimal(M, D) instead float, where M is the maximum number of digits and D is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html

Comment: @fattidare, Sid is asking this for Sql Server not for MySQL.

Comment: cast it as a decimal

Comment: @AnkitBajpai decimal exists also in SQL-Server................

Answer (score 1):

It is not being converted.  That is what the floating point representation is.  What you are seeing is the scientific/exponential format.

I am guessing that you don't want to store the data that way.  You can alter the column to use a *fixed* format representation:

```
alter table ProductAmount alter amount decimal(20, 0);
```

This assumes that you do not want any decimal places.  You can read more about decimal formats in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql).

I would strongly discourage you from using `float` unless:

- You have a real floating point number (say an expected value from a statistical calculation).
- You have a wide range of values (say, 0.00000001 to 1,000,000,000,000,000).
- You only need a fixed number of digits of precision over a wide range of magnitudes.

Floating point numbers are generally not needed for general-purpose and business applications.

Answer (score 1):

The value gets stored in a binary format, because this is what you specified by requesting `FLOAT` as the data type for the column.

The value that you store in the field is represented exactly, because 64-bit `FLOAT` uses 52 bits to represent the mantissa<sup>*</sup>. Even though you see `2.46237846387469E+15` when selecting the value back, it's only the presentation that is slightly off: the actual value stored in the database matches the data that you inserted.

> But i want to store `2462378463874687` as a value in my db

You are already doing it. This is the exact value stored in the field. You just cannot see it, because querying tool of SQL Management Studio formats it using scientific notation. When you do any computations on the value, or read it back into a `double` field in your program, you will get back `2462378463874687`.

If you would like to see the exact number in your `select` query in SQL Management Studio, use `CONVERT`:

```
CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), float_field,    128) -- See note below
```

**Note 1:** 128 is a deprecated format. It will work with SQL Server-2008, which is one of the tags of your question, but in versions of SQL Server 2016 and above you need to use `3` instead.

**Note 2:** Since the name of the column is `Amount`, good chances are that you are looking for a different data type. Look into `decimal` data types, which provide a much better fit for representing monetary amounts.

<sup>*</sup> 2462378463874687 is right on the border for exact representation, because it uses all 52 bits of mantissa.

Comment: But i want to store "2462378463874687" as a value in my db

Comment: @SidM You are already storing it. This is the exact value stored in the field.